# Faker Installion Issue

Tags: python, faker

(MyDjangoEnv) C:\Users\surya\Desktop\My_Django_Stuff\first_project>pip
install Faker
Collecting Faker
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/50/69efd9250a2be64f23ba1985e6b61ab9fcf829d7
5850044e2a8e4dfb909c/Faker-0.8.15-py2.py3-none-any.whl (741kB)
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: raw write()
returned invalid length 2 (should
 have been between 0 and 1)

What is the way to get resolve this issue, please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the github link https://github.com/joke2k/faker and clone the repo and then install the library using this method.